# Out of flags, wrong error message

Tags: bug, review-queues, flags

I was just reviewing triage like a good SO user and I ran out of flags. Naturally, I was so focused that I didn't even notice this small issue, and attempted to flag [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15120793) as too broad. I clicked Unsalvagable -> Should be closed... -> Too broad -> Flag Question. I forgot I had "0 flags remaining." So I was understandably shocked when I got the message

> You can only flag for moderator attention 19 times per day.

(I have 19 flags per day), despite the fact that I had not flagged for mod attention even once that that month, much less that day.

Now I know I was out of flags, but I think that the message is misleading, because it seems to say I ran out of mod attention flags, not out of all flags.

I suggest replacing it with a message like:

> You can only flag X times per day.